# ¿Cómo implementar un sitemap.xml en index.php, para generar un link asi /sitemap.xml

Tags: php, html, web, heroku, sitemap

Tengo una carpeta en mi escritorio la cual supongo que es mi carpeta raíz, donde tengo un archivo home.html y un archivo index.php, con los cuales con ayuda de git bash he implementado una pagina web la cual se encuentra funcionando y esta alojada en heroku https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/.
Estoy segura de que mi archivo sitemap.xml lo tengo que colocar en la carpeta de mi escritorio junto con los otros dos archivos, mi pregunta es ¿qué código debo de escribir en mi archivo index.php para obtener una dirección así https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml?, y poder visualizar mi sitemap.xml y que sea reconocido por google search console. Osea esta es mi página https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/ y deberia quedar así https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml

Comment: Hola, veo que estás empezando recién en el mundo de la programación, y estas en los conocimientos básico para emprenderlo. Siempre es bueno obtener algo de ayuda para reforzar todo esos conocimientos yo te recomiendo seguir un curso avanzado de diseño en la siguiente [fuente learn code source](https://www.facebook.com/LearnCodeSource/) son cursos online del mismo país, me atrevi a compartirte esa información porque en unas de las preguntas me dí cuenta que decía ***Portoviejo-Manabí-Ecuador*** yo soy del Carmen yo te recomiendo seguir sus cursos se aprende desde casa :) saludos.

Comment: Hola que gusto, muchas gracias por la información, escribeme este es mi Facebook Alecandra Loor (la alex) estoy con una blusa ploma este es mi correo alexa_191291@yahoo.es

Comment: estoy como alexandra.loor https://www.facebook.com/alexandra.loor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, vamos por partes, primero:

> ¿qué código debo de escribir en mi archivo index.php para obtener una dirección así https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml?

Debes escribir eXtensible Markup Language(XML) en ese archivo, que no es un lenguaje de programación estrictamente hablando.

Sobre la estructura de este archivo puedes encontrar más información en [google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=es).

Dejando eso de lado, puedes escribir ese XML manualmente, una sola vez o puedes generarlo cada XX horas, minutos o segundos usando:

- Un CRON job en el sistema operativo.
- Una línea de código en tu página principal para que se genere en cada visita.
- Cada que se llama el archivo haciendo modificaciones a tu servidor para que PHP procese e interprete los archivos xml como si fueran PHP.

Por último, para crear y manipular XML's en PHP deberías echar un vistazo a la clase `DomDocument`que puede ser instanciada con:

```
$xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
```

De igual forma los siguientes métodos son tus amigos para esta tarea:

```
$baseXML = $xml->createElement('elemento');
$elementoHijo = $xml->appendChild($baseXML);
$elementoHijo->setAttribute('elemento', 'hijo');
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta, se poquisimo de programación pero soy muy entusiasta y entiendo lo que me acabas de decir. Usted me está diciendo que usando el leguaaje de etiquetas xml en index.php obtendria una direcciión así https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml? Nota: https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/ si esta en funcionamiento. Respecto a la estrucura del archivo.xml yo lo se hacer manualmente y no tengo ningun problema, muchas gracias por la información adicional para hacerlo de manera automatico. Ahora primero quiero subirlo manualmente

Comment: sobre la clase que me acabas de mencionar, ¿tengo que introducir esto en git bash $xml = new DomDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');?. ¿y esto otro también lo tengo que introducir en git bash $baseXML = $xml->createElement('elemento');
$elementoHijo = $xml->appendChild($baseXML);
$elementoHijo->setAttribute('elemento', 'hijo');   y para introducir este codigo en git debo tener creado el archivo xml en mi carpeta raiz, y ya debo de haber escrito lenguaje xml en php?

Comment: @alexandra-loor, en efecto, si pones el archivo `sitemap.xml` junto `index.php` tu sitio quedaría como `alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml`.

Comment: La clase que te comento es una clase PHP para generar XML's por medio de PHP. Si quieres que los cambios que hagas en tu sitio se reflejen en el archivo XML en automático tendrías que hacerlo de manera programática con PHP o algo similar.

Comment: No te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta en caso de que haya respondido tu pregunta :)

Comment: ok voy a añadir el archivo a la misma carpeta donde esta home y donde está index.php, ¿pero no tengo que modificar o escribir nada en index. php?

Comment: No, tienes que generar el archivo manual, ponerlo en la raíz de tu sitio y si está bien lo podrás abrir con el url http://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/sitemap.xml